# What would be a good way to write this SQL query in a better way?

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

```
SELECT
    MAX(timestamp) as end,
    MIN(timestamp) as start, 
    (MAX(odometerKM) - MIN(odometerKM)) as distanceTravelled,
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EventData WHERE speedKPH = 0 AND timestamp >= ? AND timestamp <= ? AND  deviceID = ?)  as stopsDuration,
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EventData WHERE speedKPH != 0 AND timestamp >= ? AND timestamp <= ? AND  deviceID = ? )  as tripDuration,
    (MAX(odometerKM) - MIN(odometerKM)) / ( SELECT fuelEconomy FROM Device WHERE deviceID = ?) as fuelConsumption
FROM EventData
WHERE deviceID = ? AND timestamp >= ? AND timestamp <= ?
```

Quite confusing but I have created this query to find a summary of set of rows. Min and max timestamp are simple but to find the COUNT of rows where speed was zero and not zero, I have done an ugly hack. I am sure there is a better way to do this?

**Update**: The "?" refer to be replaced by an immature query builder of CodeIgniter. Sadly, it doesn't support named parameters yet.

Comment: Didn't you forget to include the condition `WHERE deviceID = ?` in your first two subqueries?

Comment: @Yak: Yeah. Let me edit.

Comment: Also, it looks like the same two subqueries actually calculate a *number* of Events (`COUNT()`) rather than a duration?

Answer (score 0):

You should include DeviceID, so it makes sense. Try this:

```
SELECT
DeviceID,
MAX(timestamp) as end,
MIN(timestamp) as start, 
(MAX(odometerKM) - MIN(odometerKM)) as distanceTravelled,
SUM (
  case speedKPH 
    when  0  then 1
    else 0
  end)  as stopsDuration,

SUM (
  case speedKPH 
    when  0  then 0
    else 1
  end)  as tripDuration,

(MAX(odometerKM) - MIN(odometerKM)) / Device.fuelEconomy  as fuelConsumption

FROM EventData
Join Device ON Device.deviceID = EventData.deviceID 

WHERE deviceID = ? AND timestamp >= ? AND timestamp <= ?

GROUP BY  DeviceID
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd get rid of the column subqueries. You can calculate `stopsDuration` and `tripDuration` like this (I'll leave out `fuelConsumption` for now):

```
SELECT
  MAX(timestamp) as end, MIN(timestamp) as start, 
  MAX(odometerKM) - MIN(odometerKM) as distanceTravelled,
  COUNT(speedKPH = 0 AND timestamp >= ? AND timestamp <= ?) as stopsDuration
  COUNT(speedKPH != 0 AND timestamp >= ? AND timestamp <= ?) as tripDuration
FROM EventData WHERE deviceID = ? AND timestamp >= ? AND timestamp <= ?
```

You can get rid of the `fuelComparison` subquery *column* by cross-joining to the single applicable row of the `Device` table.

```
SELECT
  (MAX(odometerKM) - MIN(odometerKM)) / dv.fuelEconomy as fuelConsumption
FROM
  EventData,
  (SELECT Device.fuelEconomy FROM Device WHERE DeviceId = ?) dv
WHERE deviceID = ? AND timestamp >= ? AND timestamp <= ?
```

Put it all together and you get this, which (on paper at least) should be faster:

```
SELECT
  MAX(timestamp) as end, MIN(timestamp) as start, 
  MAX(odometerKM) - MIN(odometerKM) as distanceTravelled,
  COUNT(speedKPH = 0 AND timestamp >= ? AND timestamp <= ?) as stopsDuration
  COUNT(speedKPH != 0 AND timestamp >= ? AND timestamp <= ?) as tripDuration,
  (MAX(odometerKM) - MIN(odometerKM)) / dv.fuelEconomy as fuelConsumption
FROM
  EventData,
  (SELECT Device.fuelEconomy FROM Device WHERE DeviceId = ?) dv
WHERE deviceID = ? AND timestamp >= ? AND timestamp <= ?
```

Comment: To reduce it more, isnt it better to create another subquery table with WHERE conditions AND eliminate WHERE in all?

Comment: I thought about that but I wasn't sure if it would break the `start` and/or `end` and/or `distanceTravelled` values. I never planned to test this so I stopped after doing things I was 100% sure of. If you can reduce it that far you should definitely post that as an answer. Feel free to use my query as a starting point - I don't have a problem with that at all :)